# Can't make materialize work by webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, materialize

Can't make materialize work by webpack. the app is base on create-reat-app

github: https://github.com/Denly/react_webapp  (fork/push a solution is appreciated)

//Error

> TypeError:
>   __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_jquery___default(...)(...).sideNav is not a function

```
   7 | class App extends Component {
   8 |   componentDidMount() {
   9 |     // Initialize collapse button
> 10 |     $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
```

// webpack.config.dev.js

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'materialize-css/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery',
      jQuery: 'materialize-css/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'materialize-css/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery',
      'window.$': 'materialize-css/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery',
      "Hammer": "hammerjs/hammer"
    }),
  ],
```

// src/index.js

```
import 'materialize-css';
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css';
import 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it.. materialize-css updated the jquery to 3.x. It needs to be the one materialize is using.

```
//App.js
import $ from 'materialize-css/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery';

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // Initialize collapse button
    $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
```